# Fail2ban - how to block searching avi, mpeg, mpg

Tags: debian, fail2ban

I have a problem with **Fail2Ban** on Debian. I want to block IP addresses that try to search for .avi, .mpeg or .mpg files on my server. I don't know what I have to search for in jail.conf to add that rule.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can [ban specific IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018312/howto-ban-ip-with-fail2ban-manually-by-command-line) using `sudo fail2ban-client -vvv set JAIL banip WW.XX.YY.ZZ`

Comment: yea, but how add rule to block only when someone tries to search for .avi files?

Comment: I thought you wanted to ban them after the fact that they searched for it, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter and add it to jail.local.

In the filter create a regex that looks for the mp4, etc in the access file.

Here is an example of one from our access logs.

```
34.209.175.228 - - [21/Jan/2019:17:01:43 -0500] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2014/10/WORK-WE-DO-TEST.mp4
```

Your regex will look something like this:

```
   <HOST> - - .mp4
```

You’ll need one line for each file type.